# How to set browser and environment from the command line in cucumber.js

Tags: javascript, configuration, cucumber, command-line-interface, cross-browser

I am a noob using Playwright with TypeScript and CucumberJs and I want to pass from the command line a String to my switch cases, something like this, on Windows. However, using set BROWSER=whatever and set ENV=whatever does not work.

I tried multiple other things but they didn't work. I want something simple like Java's System.getProperty to couple with my npx cucumber-js command

```
BeforeAll(async () => {
    const browserName = process.env.BROWSER || 'chromium';
    switch (browserName) {
        case 'firefox':
            browser = await firefox.launch(config.browserOptions);
            break;
        case 'headlessFirefox':
            browser = await firefox.launch({ headless: true });
        case 'webkit':
            browser = await webkit.launch(config.browserOptions);
            break;
        case 'headlessWebkit':
            browser = await webkit.launch({ headless: true });
        case 'headlessChromium':
            browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true });
        default:
            browser = await chromium.launch(config.browserOptions);
    }
    context = await browser.newContext();
    page = await context.newPage();
    return page;
});
```

```
export function getBaseUrl() {
    const environment = process.env.ENV || config.BASE_URL;
    switch (environment) {
        case 'DEV':
            return "devEnvPlaceholder";
        case 'STG':
            return "stagingEnvPlaceholder";
        default:
            return config.BASE_URL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my issue using https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

If someone has trouble understanding the documentation, I am happy to share.